# Use parentElement multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm editing a plugin that creates filters on an table like excel(drop-down), the problem is when I use it on a table that uses a table inside it, in fact the plugin will also take the values ​​of the sub-table.
I therefore decided to exclude from the initial array, made up of all the rows, those elements that have a parent with a table that does not have an id.
So i `forEach` array and see if have `id` like:

```
this.tds.forEach((el) =>{
   console.log(el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id); 
});
```

I was wondering if using `parentElement` three times like this is correct or there is another way

Comment: WHy would it be incorrect? Does it cause issues for you? Why are you looking for a different way? Please explain what your issue is here.

Comment: Simply use [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) instead. Most related post I could find (by [searching for the solution](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+is%3Aa+parentElement+closest+-%5Bjquery%5D)): [Better way to get DOM element](/q/65535501/4642212).

Comment: For real i don't have an issue, that work correctly but is that the best way ? @JohannesH.

Comment: "Best" is highly subjective. Best for performance? Best for robustness? Best for portability?

Comment: "Elegant code"? Also powerful, actually closest is the answer I was looking for, I don't have to duplicate a command but he executes it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly fine, as long as you're sure that the structure will always be the same.

But let's assume that you don't know if the structure will always be like this, but you do know the `class` of the parent you're looking for (or any other CSS query), then you could use the [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method to query your way up.

So let's say you want to find the closest table with an id value.

```
this.tds.forEach((el) => {
  const parent = el.closest('table:not([id=""])');
  if (parent !== null) {
    console.log(parent.id); 
  }
});
```

This will walk up the DOM tree from the `el` as starting point, doing something in the likes of `parentElement.parentElement.parentElement...` until it reaches an element that has a value in the `id` attribute.

Comment: `closest(':not([id=""])')` selects by "Id not empty", which is what I read from the question.

Comment: I didn't remember closest, i used a filter and return like return `el.closest('table').id !== '';`

Comment: @JohannesH. that's a nice query, but if any of the elements along the way also don't have an `id` value, then it will return the wrong element.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini This however won't traverse up to the next table if it finds one without an ID.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Good catch. Make it `closest('table:not([id=""])')`

Comment: @JohannesH. I am sure that the structure will always be `table with id> tr> td> table without id> element`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, then it is still the easiest way to get what you need.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier use closest with selector `not` or use `table` like my comment?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Depends on your code. Do you need a selecto that selects you the right element directly? then use the code with `:not`. Do you just need a statement that yields a boolean? then you can either use your approach or use the one from this anwer.

Comment: @ErnielZuurbier I fixed a missing closing parenthesis in your selector.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code.

But if you want to make the code a little more robust you can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
this.tds.forEach((el) =>{
   console.log(el?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement?.id); 
});
```